# How can I conditionally compile code for Catalyst?

Tags: ios, macos, mac-catalyst

I'm working on porting an iOS application to Catalyst. The Catalyst (Mac) version will have its own target.

Is there an official way to conditionally compile code just for Catalyst? Otherwise, I can add a target-specific define, but it would be better to use something more general.

Comment: Did you see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_a_mac_version_of_your_ipad_app - it shows what you can do.

Comment: I did read that, but I don't see anything about conditional compilation there.

Answer (score 31):

As seen in the documentation [Creating a Mac Version of Your iPad App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_a_mac_version_of_your_ipad_app), you do:

Swift:

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    // Code specific to Mac.
#else
    // Code to exclude from Mac.
#endif
```

Objective-C:

```c
#if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
    // Code specific to Mac.
#else
    // Code to exclude from Mac.
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks! I was specifically looking for Objective-C and didn't see the answer there. I should have specified that in my question.

Comment: It's right there in the link I provided. Just select Objective-C instead of Swift at the top of the page.

Comment: If using this in the bridging header, you also need to `#import <TargetConditionals.h>`

Comment: Hey, do you know if there is a way to target specific mac versions?

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to run code that is excluded from macCatalyst without having to use the `#else`. Note the use of ! (not).

```
#if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    print("This code will not run on macCatalyst")
#endif
```